# add vue-videobg to vuetify (cdn) without webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-video, vuetify.js

i need to add vue-videobg to vuetify in cdn without a `"magic_videobg_to_install.java.css.js.htm"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify-video-parallax"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>Hello world</v-container>

  <v-video-parallax src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" img="assets/city.png" height="600">
  Some Html Here and the video is <b>normally</b> in the background...
</v-video-parallax>


      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
 components: {
    VuetifyVideoParallax: window["vuetify-video-parallax"]
  },
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data() {
         return {
        "important": true,
        "is_video_parallax_work": "no plz help me",
        }
        }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this code work **BUT** not the video-parallax, "[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option." can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
add `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify-video-parallax"></script>` after the `vuetify`
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
      <template>
        <v-video-parallax 
        :src="src"
        img="http://prcagrimex.co.th/en/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/dummy-image-green-e1398449160839-300x214.jpg"  
        height="600">
            Some Html Here
          </v-video-parallax>
      </template>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify-video-parallax"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      data: () => ({ 
          message: 'Row',
      src: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/videos/the-couple-with-camping-backpacks-walking-to-the-mountain-top-slow-video-id1151597371',
       }),
    }).$mount('#app');
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```